# Orientation on normal bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles

Let $M \subseteq N$ be an embedded submanifold. Then if both $M$, $N$ are oriented, it is [claimed, pg87 line +17](https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/jeber_02/skripten/mainfile.pdf):

> this induces an orientation on the normal bundle of $M$.

---

Comment: This follows from the comments at the bottom of page 78 and top of page 79.

Answer (score 1):

The obstruction of the orientability is the first Stiefel-Whitney class $w_1$. Suppose that $N$ is a submanifold of $M$, we denote by $TN$ the tangent bundle of $N$, $T(N,M)$ the restriction of $TM$ to $N$, and $LN$ the normal bundle of $TN$. Remark that by using a differentiable metric one can write $T(N,M)=TN \oplus LN$. This implies that $w_1(T(N,M))=w_1(TN)w_1(LN)$. We deduce that $w_1(T(N,M))=w_1(TN)=1$ implies that $w_1(LN)=1$.

Comment: Isn't it that the orientability holds when the first Stiefel-Whitney class vanishes?